# Is it possible to use Querydsl CaseBuilder when checking for null-value in a left join?

Tags: null, left-join, case, querydsl

Is it possible to use the `CaseBuilder` like the following example? We are using Querydsl with JPA / Hibernate setup.

```
public class Foo {
    Bar bar
}
public class Bar {}

// query:
Expression<Boolean> isNull = new CaseBuilder()
    .when(foo.bar.isNull()).then(false)
    .otherwise(true)

new JPAQuery(em)
    .from(foo)
    .leftJoin(foo.bar)
    .list(foo.name, isNull);
```

When trying a similar query I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CaseNode.getFirstThenNode(CaseNode.java:43)  
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CaseNode.getDataType(CaseNode.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:152)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is syntactically possible, but currently unsupported by Hibernate. Here is a related ticket https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/185